# Angular <input [value]="model"> why do not pass twice entered value?

Tags: angular, input

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `
    <input [value]="model" (change)="setHours('24')">
    <p>{{model}}</p>
  `
})
export class KeyUpComponent_v1 {
  model = '';

  setHours(value: string) {
    this.model = value;
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hoq6rn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fkeyup.components.ts

1. enter some thing (onBlur input value=='24')
2. enter "why" again (onBlur input value=='why') 
   expect === '24'

Can we do some with this to get always input value=='24' with any entered value?

And why it happens?

Comment: What you want to know? what's the error?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to ask

Answer (score 1):

You've hardcoded the value in `(change)="setHours('24')"`, that's why you always get the same result.

To properly implement inputs please read: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: The fact of the matter is that I do not get the same value